# How can I have two panels in terminal that interact with each other?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm trying to switch to Vim and I'm liking it a lot, but one big issue I'm having is switching files I have to constantly `:wq`, `cd ...`, `ls ...`, `vi ...`, etc. I'd like to have two panels (vertical?). One is for coding and the other is for `cd`-ing/`ls`-ing/`vi`-ing. Sort of like having a file browser as in most code editors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the CtrlP plugin and ditching the idea of having a file pane. I always knew what the file name was kinda, so this works better and takes up 0 screen real estate.

https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim

Answer (score 2):

You could use [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) for directories navigation and [CommandT](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) for fast file searching.

Answer (score 1):

I second the [NERDTree plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) from @lucapette.
And also recommend [Bufferlist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1325), to quickly switch between already opened files.

Another quick solution to explore a directory would be with `:E`

```
:E ~/workspace/
```

Would list the files in the workspace dir in your home folder for you to open.

Answer (score 0):

You can `:vsp` into directory (as opposed to file).